# Python get XML Attributes from multiple nodes

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

**Input XML**

```
<component>
    <section classCode="DOCSECT" moodCode="EVN">
        <organizer classCode="CLUSTER" moodCode="EVN">
            <code code="46680005" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" displayName="Vital signs"/>
            <component>
                <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.27"/>
                    <id root="fe4dc35f-ea98-4d3c-844f-3098e3419a59"/>
                    <code code="8302-2" displayName="Height"/>
                    <statusCode code="completed"/>
                    <effectiveTime value="20110130"/>
                    <value unit="Inches" value="61.2598" xsi:type="PQ"/>
                </observation>
            </component>
            <component>
                <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.27"/>
                    <id root="95f747ac-c3f5-4de0-84eb-29f20d68e571"/>
                    <code code="3141-9" displayName="Weight"/>
                    <statusCode code="completed"/>
                    <effectiveTime value="20110130"/>
                    <value unit="lbs" value="108.00" xsi:type="PQ"/>
                </observation>
            </component>
        </organizer>
    </section>
</component>
```

**Input Namespace**

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" moodCode="EVN">
```

**Code**

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse(sample_string)
root = tree.getroot()

for each in root.findall(".//{urn:hl7-org:v3}observation/{urn:hl7-org:v3}code[@displayName='Height']"):
    print(each.attrib)
```

**Ouput**

```
{'code': '8302-2', 'displayName': 'Height'}
```

**Question**

I want to access effectiveTime value="", code="", displayName="", unit="" and value="".
But since there are multiple attributes with same name as code and value, I don't know how to reach specific elements. I don't expect help formatting the output but to paint a clear picture, at the end i am trying to get output in the form..

```
date, code, display_name, value, unit
20110130, 8302-2, Height, 61.2598, Inches
```

Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Xpath 1.0 query that gets the expected result. Tested with XML without namespaces since OP did not post a complete sample

```
"//observation[code[@displayName="Height"]]/*[self::effectiveTime | self::value | self::code]/@*[name()="value" or name()="unit" or name()="displayName"]
```

Parts of the XPath details:

- Get node containing interesting nodes:  `"//observation[code[@displayName="Height"]]"`
- Get interesting nodes `"*[self::effectiveTime | self::value | self::code]"` children of the node above. Meaning any node that is effectiveTime, value or code.
- Given the above nodes, get attributes whose names are value, unit or diaplayName: `"@*[name()="value" or name()="unit" or name()="displayName"]"`

Testing on command line

```
xmllint --xpath '//observation[code[@displayName="Height"]]/*[self::effectiveTime | self::value | self::code]/@*[name()="value" or name()="unit" or name()="displayName"]' test.xml | tr ' ' '\n'; echo
```

Result, attributes appear in document order:

```
displayName="Height"
value="20110130"
unit="Inches"
value="61.2598"
```

In case of trouble, get the node containing expected values and then find them taking it as a reference

```
// find an observation node containing a code node with a displayName attribute = "Height"
refNode = root.find(".//{urn:hl7-org:v3}observation[{urn:hl7-org:v3}code[@displayName='Height']]")
for each in refNode.findall("some xpath"):
   ...
```

Comment: Taking cues from your reply, I can reach all the attributes in a given node. But since values are in different sub-nodes I am not able to club them together. `tree = ElementTree.parse(input_file_path)
root = tree.findall('.//{urn:hl7-org:v3}observation[@classCode="OBS"]/')

for each in root:
    print(each.attrib)`

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't get the attributes as in my example so added details of the xpath parts in case it helps. Of course you have to fix my XPath adding your namespaces.

Comment: I guess I am stuck on thinking that I have to loop through all sub-nodes (hence I am trying to build it out using 'findall' instead of 'find') and when I do that, i have values segregated out in different rows `(None, None, None, None, None)
(None, None, None, None, None)
(None, '8302-2', 'Height', None, None)
(None, 'completed', None, None, None)
(None, None, None, '20170130', None)
(None, None, None, '61.2598', 'Inches')`

Comment: Your XPath is getting *all* the 6 children nodes, not a coincidence you get also 6 rows in your result. You can limit the results to what you want with a more precise XPath.